# How does Functional React Not Reset State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just tried react functional components and it seemed to work by magic. In my components function I both initialize my state and return my view. Actions within the view may call functions defined within the scope of the component function, which in turn updates the state.

My assumption was that the functional component's function was only called once, but was surprised to find it was called each time a state change occurred. If this function initializes state, and it is being called at each state change, how is my state not being reset at each state change?

Here is a keylogger component which takes key strokes from an input and displays them in a div:

```
export const KeyLogger = () => {
    const [keysLogged, setKeysLogged] = React.useState<string[]>([]);

    const logKey = (key: string) => {
        setKeysLogged(keysLogged.concat(key));
    }

    console.log("HERE");

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <input onKeyUp={ev => logKey(ev.key)}/>
            <br/>
            <div>{keysLogged}</div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

When I use this component, I see that the `keysLogged` grows as I type.

[image]

And I also see "HERE" is being logged on each keystroke.

[image]

How is this possible when the first line of my functional component appears to initialize `keysLogged` each invocation?

```
const [keysLogged, setKeysLogged] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
```

---

EDIT:

Using @Ethan Lipkind's response I found this:

> There is an internal list of “memory cells” associated with each component. They’re just JavaScript objects where we can put some data. When you call a Hook like useState(), it reads the current cell (or initializes it during the first render), and then moves the pointer to the next one. This is how multiple useState() calls each get independent local state.

So react knows which value to use based on the order `useState` is called. And because it's using `useState` and not `createState`, react knows not to reinitialize a value if a value at the memory cell location already exists.

This has an interesting affect when i switch order of when `keysLoggedA` and `keysLoggedB` are initialized in each invocation.

```
let counter = 0;
export const KeyLogger = () => {
    counter++;

    let keysLoggedA: any;
    let setKeysLoggedA: any;
    let keysLoggedB: any;
    let setKeysLoggedB: any;


    if (counter % 2 === 0) {
        [keysLoggedA, setKeysLoggedA] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
        [keysLoggedB, setKeysLoggedB] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
    } else {
        [keysLoggedB, setKeysLoggedB] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
        [keysLoggedA, setKeysLoggedA] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
    }


    const logKey = (key: string) => {
        setKeysLoggedA(keysLoggedA.concat(key));
    }

    console.log("HERE");

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <input onKeyUp={ev => logKey(ev.key)}/>
            <br/>
            <div>{keysLoggedA}</div>
            <div>{keysLoggedB}</div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

Even though I only ever call `setKeysLoggedA`, you can see `keysLoggedA` and `keysLoggedB` both get updated.

[image]

This is because it's entirely dependent on the *order* useState is called. Which makes sense, I don't know what else it could be, but it's nice to know how the magic works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

each time the state changes, it triggers a re-render which is why you see your log on each keystroke. The state is not re-initialized on each function call because of the way the `useState` hook works under the hood: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: For those who do want the state to be reset when the passed "initial value" changes, see [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14738) and the [use-state-with-deps package](https://github.com/peterjuras/use-state-with-deps).